# Singular or plural (omit repeated word)?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I'm not sure how to write this:

a) Jon was accepted to Northwestern and Cornell University.

b) Jon was accepted to Northwestern and Cornell Universities.

In this example, I'm pretty sure you can omit the repeated word "university." Since we're dealing with two universities, I think b) may be correct. However, in example a), "university" is right next to the singular "Cornell," so I'm not sure.

Comment: (a) would only be correct if there'a a single university called "Northwestern and Cornell". (b) is fine if *both of **two*** universities (Northwestern ***and*** Cornell) offered Jon a place, and that's how it would normally be expressed. There's nothing actually *wrong* with the more verbose form *Jon was accepted to Northwestern University and Cornell University* (where each university is ***singular***), but most native speakers wouldn't be likely to use that form very often, if at all.

Comment: The second sentence is fine but, stylistically, you should *not* be capitalizing *universities*. It's not being used as part of a proper noun, but as a plural common noun. (*The two universities*, not *the two Universities*.)

Comment: But don't you capitalize Cornell University by itself?

Comment: Isn't Cornell University a proper noun? In this particular case, we use "universities" because it applies to the plural common noun as opposed to each individual proper noun (Cornell University).

Answer (score 1):

The name of each institution contains the word "University", however it would be correct to abbreviate them to simply "Northwestern" and "Cornell".

As both are universities, you could write:

> Jon was accepted to Northwestern and Cornell universities.

This is my recommended approach. However, it would also be valid to say:

> Jon was accepted to Northwestern University and Cornell University.